# Can't step into function

Tags: c, gdb

Source File Structure:

```
    main.c
    Feature/
        Feature1.c
```

Could someone tell me about what differences between

```
gcc -g main.c Feature/Feature1.c -o Program
```

and

```
gcc -c -g main.c -o main.o
gcc -c -g Feature/Feature1.c -o Feature/Feature1.o
gcc -g main.o Feature/Feature1.o -o Program
```

I found that gdb could step into functions implemented in Feature1.c with compiling method 1 but do not work with compiling method 2. What should I do if projects are compiled with method 2?

Comment: "do not work with compiling method 2". That shouldn't be the case. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code and your exact gdb sesssion log.

Comment: Actually, I am using visual studio code and things listed above are the contents of Makefile. I can't reproduce the issue somehow now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer reproducible.

Comment: I think you have to understand the target and dependency in Makefile, and you have to know how compiler compiles your code.
This link [https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html] will help you, i think